# После смены хостинга не находит страницы с товарами

Tags: joomla

При открытии любого товара возникает ошибка

> Oops! That page can’t be found

Comment: Пожалуйста, всё, что относится к вопросу размещайте прямо в вопросе. Сообщество не приветствует ссылки на сторонние сайты.

Comment: joomla имеет миллиард проблем, как с работой с sql так и других, в вашем случае проблема лежит на поверхности , все ссылки в joomla не относительные да ещё и с протоколом.